# Java Character IO between java executions

Tags: java, io, java-compiler-api

Using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` and `javax.tools.ToolProvider`, I'm wrapping a user-input string (which should be a method) with a predefined class all within a large string and executing it within my code. Is there a way to (in the same code) instantiate the class that was compiled (as it doesn't exist until runtime) to test said function with a predefined set of cases?

Example: User is prompted to write a method that returns the opposite boolean sent to it as an argument.

User types in said method.

I wrap a generic class around the method, and use a predefined set of test cases (true, false) to check it's functionality (should get false, true back)

Comment: @r0ast3d: Class.forName only helps if one stores the class somewhere where the class loader of the current class will look for this class.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, by reading the generated class into `byte[]` and using [Classloader.defineClass(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) to resolve/construct a Class object. To resolve the class properly, all resources referred by this class should be available to the classloader instance you're using. Once you have a Class object, you can instantiate it and invoke the method using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).